# ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') not working in nginx

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, magento

Hi we have recently switched our Magento application from Apache to nginx and PHP-FPM on CentOS 5.6. We have an external payment gateway that sends us back some transaction information. The PHP file that handles this has a if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') condition.

There is code above this IF statement in that PHP file which is executing normally. However, all the code inside the IF statement is not being executed.

My etc/nginx/conf.d/domain.conf file:

```
fastcgi_read_timeout 240;    

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain.com;
    rewrite / $scheme://www.$host$request_uri permanent; ## Forcibly prepend a www
}

server {
    listen 80 default;

    ## SSL directives might go here
    listen 443 default ssl;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/ssl/domain.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/domain.key;

    server_name www.domain.com *.domain.com; ## Domain is here twice so server_name_in_redirect will favour the www
    root /path/to/root/;

    location / {
        index index.html index.php; ## Allow a static html file to be shown first
        try_files $uri $uri/ @handler; ## If missing pass the URI to Magento's front handler
        expires 30d; ## Assume all files are cachable
    }

    location /phpmyadmin {
        auth_basic "Restricted Access";
        auth_basic_user_file htpasswd_file;
        alias /path/to/phpmyadmin/;
        index index.php; ## Allow a static html file to be shown first
        try_files $uri $uri/ @fastcgi;
    }

    ## These locations would be hidden by .htaccess normally
    location ^~ /app/                { deny all; }
    location ^~ /includes/           { deny all; }
    location ^~ /lib/                { deny all; }
    location ^~ /media/downloadable/ { deny all; }
    location ^~ /pkginfo/            { deny all; }
    location ^~ /report/config.xml   { deny all; }
    location ^~ /var/                { deny all; }

    location /var/export/ { ## Allow admins only to view export folder
        auth_basic           "Restricted"; ## Message shown in login window
        auth_basic_user_file htpasswd; ## See /etc/nginx/htpassword
        autoindex            on;
    }

    location  /. { ## Disable .htaccess and other hidden files
        return 404;
    }

    location @handler { ## Magento uses a common front handler
        rewrite / /index.php;
    }

    location ~ .php/ { ## Forward paths like /js/index.php/x.js to relevant handler
        rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last;
    }   


    location ~ .php$ { ## Execute PHP scripts
        if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite / /index.php last; } ## Catch 404s that try_files miss

        expires        off; ## Do not cache dynamic content
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_param  HTTPS $fastcgi_https;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_CODE default; ## Store code is defined in administration > Configuration > Manage Stores
        fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_TYPE store;
        include        fastcgi_params; ## See /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params
    }
}
```

The relevant parts of our /etc/nginx/conf.d file:

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

```
log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

sendfile        on;
autoindex off;
map $scheme $fastcgi_https { ## Detect when HTTPS is used
    default off;
    https on;
}
#tcp_nopush     on;

keepalive_timeout  10;

gzip  on;
gzip_comp_level 2;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_types      text/plain text/html text/css application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

#
# The default server
#
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  _;

# Load config files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
```

}

Any ideas what we can do to get this POST condition working?

Answer (score 2):

Your `/etc/nginx/fastcgi_params` file should contain (among several other things) the following line:

```
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
```

This is as shipped. Check to make sure it wasn't altered.

In my own PHP scripts I take a very simple shortcut to check if it was a POST request:

```
if ($_POST) {
    # Process some POST variables
}
# Display the web page
```